# Activity Manager Start Option

Tags: android, adb

In this command :

```
adb shell am start -a com.example.package/com.example.package.ActivityName
```

What does the **-a** mean? I am seeing it as a start option but I can't seem to find any explanation from googling what the **-a** and sometimes I see a **-n** option as well.

I would expect this site to have all the explanations but if it does I can not locate it.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: `adb shell` is starting a common shell on Andorid side so everything that comes after is a Linux shell command unrelated to adb. This means adb help doesn't cover it. If you want to see the help of `am` execute `adb shell am help`.

Comment: confusingly enough, it's on `adb`'s page, but as @Robert mentioned, they are independent: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am

Answer (score 1):

First of all your command won't work with `-a` argument as it has no action defined. :)

- `-a` means action, for ex: `-a android.intent.action.VIEW`
- `-c` means category, for ex: `-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE`
- `-d` means deeplink, for ex: `-d "example:iamdeeplink"`
- `-n` means `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, so it will create a new task and launch your Activity there even though you might already have it running. It will start it from scratch.
- Leaving `-n` argument out, would bring the task with your the Activity to the foreground if it exists, if not it will create a new one.